# Авторизация в Angular. Доступ к ресурсам приложения не авторизованным пользователям

Tags: angularjs, безопасность, интерфейс, auth, ux

Имеет ли смысл закрывать доступ не авторизованным пользователям к ресурсам приложения? Например при входе нас встречает страница с логином и паролем, если мы не знаем пароль, но хотим увидеть что внутри, мы можем это сделать изменив код прям в броузере. Да, доступ к данным мы таким образом не получим, но насколько это правильно и влияет ли это на безопасность приложения в целом?

Comment: Настройками сервера можно закрыть, но по сути никакого смысла в этом нет, если человек увидит какой то шаблон страницы, данные загружаются с сервера, а там проверка сессии